# Titanium.App.iOS.LocalNotification doesn't fire after 20 mins in background

Tags: ios7, titanium, uilocalnotification

I have a timer made in Titanium (3.1.3) for iOS 7. I want it to fire a notification when the timer is finished. It works perfectly until the app is placed in the background for more than 20 minutes. If the app is placed in the background for more than 20 minutes, the user don't get any notification.

This is my code:

```
var notification = Ti.App.iOS.scheduleLocalNotification({
    alertBody:L('timer_finished_alert_title'),
    badge:1,
    sound: notificationSound,
    date:new Date(new Date().getTime() + timeLeft)
});
```

How can I fire this notification if the user has left the app in the background for more than 20 minutes (`timeLeft > 1200000`)?

Comment: I found a solution: https://github.com/benbahrenburg/LocalNotify. Works with iOS 7.

Answer (score 0):

That is a limitation of iOS Background Service in Titanium.

From the [documentation](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Titanium.App.iOS.BackgroundService)

> **Background Service Limitations**
>
> A background service is subject to limitations imposed by the operating system, such as
>
> - The OS limits the total amount of time a background service can run for after the application is paused, typically to no more than 10
>     minutes.
> - The OS may terminate the background service at any point to reclaim resources.